# Is it possible to check for multiple attributeChanges with a single scriptJob in Maya?

Tags: python, maya

I would like to create a **single** scriptJob that checks for an attributeChange in **both Translates and Rotates**. I have been unsuccessful at finding information on whether this is possible and wanted to ask here before resorting to creating separate scriptJobs for each.

I have tried the script below but although it does not error, it also does not process the attributeChange on the rotate.

```python
import maya.cmds as cmds

my_cube = cmds.polyCube()[0]

def check_attribute_change():
    print('attribute change detected:')

main_scriptjob = cmds.scriptJob(attributeChange=["{}.translate".format(my_cube), check_attribute_change] or ["{}.rotate".format(my_cube), check_attribute_change], killWithScene=True)
```